# How to Jump-Start PhoneGap App Development

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, cordova

I am starting to develop an app HTML, CSS & JS based mobile app. But instead of starting from scratch how do I jump start it.
I thought using the android Gmail,nearbuy/groupon or the nowadays very common layout.
That is:

Have a Sidebar on left with hamburger button with on the Top transition.
The title of the app or whatever needed at the center of the head.
(Left of head has Hamburger)

And have tabs under the heading with different options.

So, I was looking for possible free bootstrap for the same hopefully with Material design.
Didn't come across fulfilling all the needs.
I guess this layout is very common and hence, should have an available template.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8ZoPBqpDIo4bVAwUXhtczlFVm8/view?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8ZoPBqpDIo4OWI4WkplbHFTVlU/view?usp=sharing

PS: Can't put up images as I'm new to StackOverflow & hence, lack the reputation for that.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend a technique or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Comment: Have a look at ionic creator, you can template an app, but you're going to have to know your way around angular js and the cordova framework to get further than a shell. http://creator.ionic.io

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look to [nativeDroid2](http://nativedroid.godesign.ch/material/). It is free, with Material design and the sidebar you want!

Comment: Could you please explain How I set  it up for PhoneGap ! I like it a lot